# Looking for working (complete project) example for OAuth 2.0 Access to gmail

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

I have read [Oauth2 Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html) but still am yet to get a start to finish working example.

I am a beginner and struggling to get a solution working.

I am just about to the point where I am willing to pay someone to code this for me. But it seems like it should be fairly simple and that there has to be a start to finish working example out there.

So, do you have an example of an Android app that uses OAuth 2.0 to enable the sending of email via gmail? I also need an example of using the users contacts to prepopulate a list for the user to choose from as the recipient of the email.

If I could find a free, complete example I would be indebted forever.

NOTE: I posted a similar question here... [looking for Android Gmail SMTP Oauth example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910412/looking-for-android-gmail-smtp-oauth-example)

And the answer was good but being a beginner I was never able to get it to work.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some of this work on the web side of things.  Google says the oauth authentication for Android is similar in it's process.  I found this link with a sample showing using [OAuth with SMTP](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html).  It's available in a few languages, including [Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode).

I also have a C# sample of how to perform the [Oauth in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376166/oauth-with-google-data-api-for-net-returning-http-400-bad-request/7854919#7854919).

Answer (score 8):

I didn't have time to implement Google OAuth2, 

but I can suggest you to make use of this open source library.

[generic oauth2 login for android](https://github.com/wareninja/generic-oauth2-login-for-android)

covers OAuth2 implementation for Facebook, Foursquare, Gowalla. 
I would assume that should be easy to extend for Google, as OAuth2 is pretty much standard and communities differs mostly on loading user profile part.

Comment: f.y.i. recently I also added Facebook SSO integration to that project

Comment: Great example, but is it possible to use oauth2 without the webview?