# Logging in using facebook in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication

In my Android App, there are two ways to log in:

-one is through a regular username and pass that one has made through the site
-the other is logging in using your facebook account that would be linked to your username

if using the first way, a session ID is set when calling a PHP function when logging in.

I have properly set up logging in with facebook with the tutorial on their android API page, but there are certain issues such as --

How would I go about creating a proper session ID/session when logging in with a facebook account? 
Most importantly, how would logging in work using facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use OAuth integration with Facebook, this will make your app fully integrated with Facebook.
This answer may help on implementing also for Facebook -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030462/492918